Force Change Password in ASP.NET Core
I am configuring my application to handle the following scenario: when I create a new user as an admin, a temporary (random) password is generated for that user. After the user logs in for the first time, they are required to change their password. This requirement is tracked using the MustChangePassword field in the AppUser : Identity class.
I want to enforce that users must change their password immediately after logging in. If the user tries to access any other links, they should be redirected to the Change Password page. I thought configuring middleware would be the best approach for this.
However, with my current configuration (see below), even when I submit the change password form, it still redirects to /Account/ChangePassword.
public class CheckPasswordChangeMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CheckPasswordChangeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, UserManager<AppUser> userManager, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);

            if (user != null && user.MustChangePassword && !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account/ChangePassword"))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Account/ChangePassword");
                return;
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePassword model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var result = await _accountService.ChangePasswordAsync(model);
    if (result)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "An error occurred while changing the password.");
    return View(model);
}

public async Task<bool> ChangePasswordAsync(ChangePassword model)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var changePasswordResult = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, model.CurrentPassword, model.NewPassword);

    if (changePasswordResult.Succeeded)
    {
        user.MustChangePassword = false;
        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Show us the code where you reset user.MustChangePassword to false.

@dai you can check again

This is only a suggstion (and it won't fix the problem), but I recommend you avoid using _httpContextAccessor - instead you could pass ClaimsIdentity in as a parameter in  _accountService.ChangePasswordAsync.

Set a  breakpoint at the if (user != null && user.MustChangePassword && !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account/ChangePassword")) to see which part is not pass the if checking.

I always advise on using logging to know how far your code debugs.. based on the information you provided above, one isn't really sure up to what point does it execude before it redirects because everything seems file. Try and use logging in your application. Every transation you make, especially during development, add a logger.logInformation ... then when an unexpected behaviour happens, you're sure to look at the console output and see what steps where executed... and that you way you will know exactly where to look.

The best way would be to not add that MustChangePassword field in your AppUser there's no need for it. You will only ever use it once and it will remain in there unused.
Instead, add a claim against that user with type new Claim("MUST_CHANGE_PASSWORD","").
In your middleware:
public async Task InvokeAsync (HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (context.User.HasClaim("MUST_CHANGE_PASSWORD","") && context.Request.Path != "/Account/ChangePassword")
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Account/ChangePassword");
            return;
        }
    }

    await _next(context);
}

In your ChangePassword HttpPost method remove that claim userManager.RemoveClaimAsync(User, new Claim("MUST_CHANGE_PASSWORD","")) once password is changed.
